# Graphics in-line with wrapping text

Tags: graphics, formatting, text

I am trying to get several lines of text to align next to an image, but only one line appears. How can I get the rest of the next paragraph to appear next to Figure 1? TIA!!!

[image: Help please]

Code used:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{Lithium-ion battery operation}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{"LIB_image".png}
    \label{fig:LIB_image}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you show us the code you use for this?

Comment: see the wrapfig package

Comment: Sorry, here is the code:

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
 \caption{Lithium-ion battery operation}
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{"LIB_image".png}
 \label{fig:LIB_image}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}

Comment: What is TIA ???

Comment: Please make your code compilable. You can use a standard image (e.g. `example-image-a`). Also, your example doesn't have any long text in it.

Comment: It makes no sense to put a `figure` in a `minipage`. Do you want a `minipage` inside the `figure`, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know. I'm a new user, i just wanted to get the figure on the left side of the page, have it populate to the list of figures, and then have text in-line on the right of the figure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \caption{Lithium-ion battery operation}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
        \label{fig:LIB_image}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
&
\parbox{0.45\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Your text is obviously shorter than what lipsum produced...

[image]